Literature Search in Homotopy Theory
I am searching for a result in the literature which I found two months ago but did not properly record. I just wrote down the following information about it.
Theorem (Hurewics 1939, Asphäresche Räume). Let $X,Y$ be spherical spaces. Then the set of homotopy classes of maps $[X,Y] = \frac{Hom(\pi_1(X),\pi_1(Y))}{Inn(\pi_1(Y))}$ where $Inn(\pi_1(Y))$ are the inner automorphisms of $\pi_1(Y)$.
I did not find the paper "Asphärische Räume" and I would like to check the definitions used to state the theorem as well as its proof. If someone has more information about this result, please share it.

Perhaps you'll find it with the correct spelling: Witold Hurewicz. The work is mentioned here.

I suspect the hypothesis should refer to aspherical spaces.

You are looking for

Witold Hurewicz, Beiträge zur Topologie der Deformationen IV: Asphärische Räume, Proc. Akad. Wetensch. Amsterdam 39 (1936), 215-224.

Here is a digitized version.  (I found this from this MO post.  As mentioned there, this result is also proven in Hatcher.)
